# Apache forwarding to tomcat shows a blank page

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have an application running on tomcat at `http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext`. The host name in `server.xml` points to `www.example.com`. I do not have `localhost` anymore. I am using apache to forward requests to tomcat using `mod_proxy`. Things work fine as long as the `ProxyPath` is `/mycontext`. The server name setup in virtual host is `www.abc.com` and `http://www.abc.com/mycontext` works fine. However I would like to ignore the context path and simply use `http://www.abc.com/` to forward requests to `http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext`. When I do this, apache shows me a blank page. What am I missing here? I have not changed anything in `server.xml` except the default host to `www.example.com`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.abc.com

 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On

 <Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext
 ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext
 </VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the relevant bits of your httpd.conf file to the question?

Comment: I have added the virtual host settings. Is there anything else I should add?

Answer (score 2):

Matching trailing slashes are important in mod_proxy.

```
ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext
```

This will take a request to `http://www.abc.com/something` and proxy it to `http://www.example.com:9090/mycontextsomething` - not terribly helpful!

Try this configuration, instead:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext/
```

---

Also - if Tomcat's expecting `www.example.com` as a host header, then you probably do not want that `ProxyPreserveHost On` directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The solution partially worked. With the trailing slash added, a page should be shown when   http ://www.abc.com/ is requested which corresponds to http ://www.example.com:9090/mycontext/. Instead it goes to the "It works" page. For other URLs such as http ://www.abc.com/test it does take me to http ://www.example.com:9090/mycontext/test. How do I solve the first bit?

Comment: Is it Apache's "It works" page, or Tomcat's?

Comment: It is Apache's "It works page."

Comment: Interesting... are you sure the request to `/` has the correct host header to get mapped to this virtual host?

Comment: I checked  the apache access log. It shows that  a request made to / gets directed to /mycontext/. Should it explicitly show http://www.example.com:9090/mycontext/

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Do you need for it to make that request without the trailing slash?  That'll be more complicated to add to the config.

Comment: Essentially my tomcat setup is serving a JSP page at :9090/mycontext/ and I would like http: //www.abc.com/ to get redirected to this page. Does it involve rewrite rules setting up for just this redirection ?

Comment: No, that should be working just fine.  Can you clarify what you meant by "It shows that a request made to / gets directed to /mycontext/" - is that not what you're looking to achieve?